# How can I disable URL in php

Tags: php

Using anchor tag I am passing some variable to another page (say profile.php) due to this the variable and its value can be seen on URL. I want to avoid user form making any changes on URL.I had got an solution HTACCESS but I don't want to use it. Rather how can i disable URL or avoid the user from making any changes

Comment: Pass data using `$_POST` instead of using anchor? Although storing value in hidden input isn't foolproof either, at least it will not be as simple as changing a value in the URL.

Comment: Ya but its the requirement of operation to pass it using anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

You just can't...

You should use post method instead of get and use hidden input.